# Refresh cursor after change in query - onStart()?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

In onCreate(), I define a cursor and move down in the results using a button :

```
        final Cursor cursor = (Cursor) WoordData.fetchset(USERCHOICE);

               btnVolgende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(View v) {   

              tv.setText(cursor.getString(0)); 

                  cursor.moveToNext();
                  if (cursor.isAfterLast()){                
                      cursor.moveToFirst();            
        }}});
```

In a seperate activity (through Preferences) I allow the user to change the value of USERCHOICE.

Question : How to I re-load the cursor with the new query (new value of USERCHOICE) when the user returns to the main activity?

thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Christian, I solved it. I'm not sure this is the cleanest solution, though..

I created a boolean called `resetneeded`.

In the clickbutton code I do :

`btnVolgende.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

            if (resetneeded) {
                cursor = (Cursor) WoordData.fetchset(kernset);

                resetneeded = false;
            }
                startManagingCursor(cursor);
                tvFlitswoord.setText(cursor.getString(0)); 
                cursor.moveToNext();
            if (cursor.isAfterLast()){

                cursor.moveToFirst(); 
            }}

          }`

And then, in the onStart(), I set the boolean `resetneeded` to true.

// EDIT - 2nd Solution

In the end, I decided to use an ArrayList for passing the words to the TextView (and cycling through it with the button). An ArrayList seems easier to handle and less fragile..

The code :

```
    public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();    
    getPrefs();
    wordlistarray.clear();
    cursor = (Cursor) WoordData.fetchset(kernset);       
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while(!cursor.isAfterLast()) {

        String wordtoadd = cursor.getString(0);
        wordlistarray.add(wordtoadd);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }       

            for(int i = 0; i < wordlistarray.size();
                    i++){ Log.d("word in array", "" + wordlistarray.get(i)); }
```